# How to create a global shortcut while using JQuery noconflict

Tags: jquery

How to declare a global window object while using jQuery.noConflict().

I am using following way to avoid Jquery conflict with Mootools

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now I would like to create global shortcut in jquery and tried as

```
 window.cc = function() {// code}
```

But fails and return error as cc not deined.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating explicit no conflict object we can use `jQuery` in place of `$` or your no conflict object name.

Answer (score 1):

Closures?

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function($){
    //code goes here
    // here $ is now jQuery
})(jQuery);

// here $ is not jQuery
```

and in any of these you can use `$` to refer to the jQuery object.

***note:** I'd also make sure jQuery loads up after any other framework for `.noConflict()` to work.*

Comment: I'd call this the canonical way of not caring about noConflict.

Comment: @Mu actually i meant that you'd use this aswell as no conflict. At my work we use `jQuery.noConflict` and this is how to use `$` when I need only jQuery.

Comment: And I meant "not caring about whether noConflict is used or not" so we're agreeing with each other.